# Cant debug SpringMVC application using springSTS

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am working with STS in eclipse Juno, Spring 3.1.1 hibernate 4.1, tomcat 7 and mySQL.

I tried to debug my application by:

1. right-clicking on the server (in the server view) ->"restart at debug".
2. adding the breakpoints in my code.
3. selecting "debug on server".

but it just launch the application without stopping at the breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did the server restart when you clicked on "Restart a server in debug mode"? Check your log.

If not, kill it and start by clicking on "Start a server in debug mode" (the little bug in the Servers view) instead of using the green/white arrow ("Run").

Comment: Aaron i did "Start a server in debug mode", just like you said, but still, it launches the application without stoping in the breakpoints..

Comment: Add a `System.out.println()` or logging call in the same place. If you see this, then debugging doesn't work. If you don't see the output, the code simply isn't called and you need to find out why.

Comment: Aaron you were right, by bad..
Anton you were right as well (it did not rich the breakpoint)..

Answer (score 1):

The other option is that your breakpoints are never reached. The code goes along a different route.